# Error loading location southamerica-west1: BigQuery Data Transfer Service does not yet support location: southamerica-west1

Tags: google-bigquery

The error message is showing up in my billing export project: "Error loading location southamerica-west1: BigQuery Data Transfer Service does not yet support location: southamerica-west1". According to your documentation of "Regions and Zones" at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones, the "southamerica-west1" does not exist.

I am not sure if it is related. All of my views in the SQL workspace in the same project can not be previewed. No results are displayed after my clicking the "Preview" tab.

Answer (score 3):

I'm seeing the same error, it started happening around the 6th or 7th of May.  I think the preview tab for views is new.  I do have that tab now, but it doesn't seem to ever populate.  Table preview works as it always has.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with a new location opening in Santiago, Chile.  Maybe they are testing the new datacenter or enabling some services.